# PostgresQL: passing a partial file path as a command line parameter

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm writing a script to export a subset of data from a PostgreSQL instance, and I'm running into a bit of trouble trying to programmatically construct an output file path.

What I would like to be able to do is something like:

```
psql -d mydb -f my_script.sql -v out_path="'/path/to/my/output/dir/'"
```

Which I have attempted with the following simple example

```sql
COPY my_table TO :out_path || 'file.csv' WITH CSV;
```

However this results in the following error:

```
psql:my_script.sql:4: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "||"
LINE 1: ...path/to/my/output/dir/' || 'my_tabl...
```

Is there a better way to piece together the output path I want in the script? Am I going about this all wrong? Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you should not to use operator `||`. It is SQL operator, and `COPY` doesn't allow expression there.

`psql` variables are concatenated by default. So in this case `||` operator is useless.

```
\set out_path /path/to/my/output/dir/
\echo :out_path/file_csv

postgres=# \set out_path /path/to/my/output/dir/
postgres=# \echo :out_path/file_csv
/path/to/my/output/dir//file_csv
```

If you don't run this script under super user, then you cannot to write to server file system. Is not good do these operation under super user. So probably you would to use `\COPY` commands, that is joined with client side files system.

So your script can looks like:

```
-- does concat too
\set file_path :out_path 'file.csv' 
\copy my_table to :file_path csv
```